# Parallax scrolling - stutter

Tags: html, css

I am using the parallax scrolling effect, but when I try
to scroll down the page there is a visible stuttering.
How can I get rid of that?

[This is my code][1]

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYdGpj
```

Comment: This looks like a client problem. I could scroll down without any stuttering. This depends too much on your used browser, PC and graphics card.

Comment: I opened it with mozila and it was working perfectly! Thanks for the advice.